# Angular 6 : Not able to fetch individual data from different component's JSON object

Tags: json, angular

**Scenario:**
In Component1, I have a table, I am sending single row's data as a JSON object to Component2's object

**Expected result:**
I should be able to fetch data using object2, eg. `object2.id = id1`, `object2.title = title1`

**Actual result:** I am getting undefined for values in object2, `object2.id= undefined` , `object2.title = undefined`

**What I tried:**
In Component1 I used `JSON.stringify(obj)` and in Component2 I was using `JSON.parse(obj)` to get the object values, but I was getting `[obj obj]` on alert the JSON object.
I got confused as to how did JSON automatically got converted to Obj without using any JSON.parse.

**Good news is, data is being passed to object2, when I alert object2 I get the whole object string with all values.
but when I try to populate single value it gives me undefined msg inspite of the values being present**

Any idea how else i can check why it is not working ?

Not sure what exactly I am missing, **I am searching since past couple of days, did not find any solution on this or any other site.**
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code:
**Component1**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'myjds',
  templateUrl: './myjds.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myjds.component.scss'],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ThemeModule,
    NgxEchartsModule, Ng2SmartTableModule,
    NgxChartsModule, ChartModule, NgxSpinnerModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    StatusCardComponent,
    ContactsComponent,
    EchartsPieComponent,
    EchartsBarComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: []

})

export class MyjdsComponent implements OnInit {

  config: ToasterConfig;
  private message = null;

  position = 'toast-top-right';
  animationType = 'flyLeft';
  title = 'Result';
  content = `I'm cool toaster!`;
  timeout = 5000;
  toastsLimit = 5;
  type = 'info';

  isNewestOnTop = true;
  isHideOnClick = true;
  isDuplicatesPrevented = false;
  isCloseButton = true;
  EntityID;
  LoginUserId;

  jdData: JobDescription[] = [];
  indJobDescription = {} as JobDescription;
  source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();
  serachResults = [];
  public nijobmobile;
  public nijobcontactemail;

  constructor(
    private ServiceObj: ApiService, 
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, 
    private modalService: NgbModal, 
    private toasterService: ToasterService, 
    private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.EntityID = localStorage.getItem("Entity");
    this.LoginUserId = localStorage.getItem("LoginID");
  }
  private showToast(type: string, title: string, body: string) {
    this.config = new ToasterConfig({
      positionClass: this.position,
      timeout: this.timeout,
      newestOnTop: this.isNewestOnTop,
      tapToDismiss: this.isHideOnClick,
      preventDuplicates: this.isDuplicatesPrevented,
      animation: this.animationType,
      limit: this.toastsLimit,
    });
    const toast: Toast = {
      type: type,
      title: title,
      body: body,
      timeout: this.timeout,
      showCloseButton: this.isCloseButton,
      bodyOutputType: BodyOutputType.TrustedHtml,
    };
    this.toasterService.popAsync(toast);
  }
  ngOnInit() {   
    this.loadJobDescription();
  }
  loadJobDescription(jdData?) {  
    if (jdData == null || jdData == undefined || jdData == 0) {
      alert("data null e ");
      this.spinner.show();
      let body = JSON.stringify({
        nispname: "nijobdescriptionsearch_sp",
        ptype: "alljobdescription",
        pnijobdescriptionid: 0,
        pniuserid: Number(this.LoginUserId),
        pnicompid: this.EntityID
      });
      alert("body string value : " + body);
      this.ServiceObj.apicall(body).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.spinner.hide();
          let data: any = res;
          if (data.results.Table.length > 0) {
            alert("table returns values:" + data.results.Table.length);
            this.jdData = data.results.Table;            
            localStorage.setItem('Message', JSON.stringify(this.jdData));
            this.source.load(this.jdData);            
          }
        },
        (err) => {
          this.spinner.hide();
        }
      );
    }
    else {
      alert("data ahe baba");
      let loginUserId = localStorage.getItem("LoginID");
      alert("loginUserId: " + loginUserId);
      this.spinner.show();
      let body = JSON.stringify({
        nispname: "nijobdescriptionsearch_sp",
        ptype: "individualJD",
        pnijobdescriptionid: jdData.nijobdescriptionid,
        pniuserid: Number(this.LoginUserId),
        pnicompid: this.EntityID
      });
      alert("body stringify:" + body);
      this.ServiceObj.apicall(body).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.spinner.hide();
          let data: any = res;
          if (data.results.Table.length > 0) {
            alert("data length" + data.results.Table.length);
            this.indJobDescription = data.results.Table;
            localStorage.setItem('Message1', JSON.stringify(this.indJobDescription));
            // alert("result of indjobdescription: " + JSON.stringify(this.indJobDescription));
            const activeModal = this.modalService.open(IndJobDescriptionComponent, {
              size: 'lg',
              backdrop: 'static',
              container: 'nb-layout',
            });
          }
        },
        (err) => {
          this.spinner.hide();
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Component2**

```
  selector: 'commentresult',
  templateUrl: './indjobdescription.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./indjobdescription.component.scss']
})
export class IndJobDescriptionComponent implements OnInit {

  private msg: string = '';
  private msg1: string = "";
  public dialog: any;
  public dialog1 :any;
  public existingstaffid = [];
  errorMsgRolename: string = '';
  errorMsgRoledescription: string = '';
  isValidRolename: boolean = true;
  isValidRoledescription: boolean = true;
  public ShlocationAutoComplete;
  public ShroleAutoComplete;
  public ShskillAutoComplete;
  public ShdomainAutoComplete;
  public ShcertAutocomplete;
  public alldata;
  public nijobmobile;
  public nijobcontactemail;


  pager: any = {};
  pagedItems: any[];

  jdData: JobDescription[] = [];  
  indJobDescription = {} as JobDescription;

  LoginUserId = localStorage.getItem("LoginID");
  source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private data: DataService,
    private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    private ServiceObj: ApiService, 
    private pagerService: PagerService,
    private toasterService: ToasterService) {
    this.EntityID = localStorage.getItem("Entity");

  }
  profile: any;
  private EntityID: string;
  private message = null;
  config: ToasterConfig;
  position = 'toast-top-right';
  animationType = 'flyLeft';
  title = 'Result';
  content = `I'm cool toaster!`;
  timeout = 5000;
  toastsLimit = 5;
  type = 'info';
  isNewestOnTop = true;
  isHideOnClick = true;
  isDuplicatesPrevented = false;
  isCloseButton = true;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.msg1 = localStorage.getItem("Message1");   
    //this.indJobDescription = JSON.parse(this.msg1);  //on doing alert, this line is returning [obj obj]   
    alert("user id: " + this.indJobDescription.nijobcreateuserid);

  }

  closeModal() {
    this.activeModal.close();
  }

  private showToast(type: string, title: string, body: string) {
    this.config = new ToasterConfig({
      positionClass: this.position,
      timeout: this.timeout,
      newestOnTop: this.isNewestOnTop,
      tapToDismiss: this.isHideOnClick,
      preventDuplicates: this.isDuplicatesPrevented,
      animation: this.animationType,
      limit: this.toastsLimit,
    });
    const toast: Toast = {
      type: type,
      title: title,
      body: body,
      timeout: this.timeout,
      showCloseButton: this.isCloseButton,
      bodyOutputType: BodyOutputType.TrustedHtml,
    };
    this.toasterService.popAsync(toast);
  }

  SaveData() {
    let t = window.location.host;
    let tvpselectiondtl: tvp_selectiondtl[] = [];
    let LoginUserId = localStorage.getItem("LoginID");
  }
}
```

PFB screenshot of the JSON string, sorry console.log is not working so had to take screen shot of the alert,

[image]

Comment: Attach the code of component 1 and component 2 how you are passing and reading them

Comment: Hi Himanshu, I have updated my question with the code. Request you to take a look.

Comment: Do one last thing console.log(this.msg1) Need to see JSON Structure as you are saying values are present.

Comment: thanks for your reply, have updated in the question, couldn't paste it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in json you are storing an array of objects .

```
this.msg1 = localStorage.getItem("Message1");   
this.indJobDescription = JSON.parse(this.msg1);  //on doing alert, this line is 
     returning [obj obj]   
alert("user id: " + this.indJobDescription[0].nijobcreateuserid);   //It is array
```

If there is multiple entry of indJobDescription then use *ngFor  to read each object.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < this.indJobDescription.length ; i++) {
      var jobCreateUserId= this.indJobDescription[i].nijobcreateuserid;
      ..........
  }
```

and it will solve your issue.

keep this simple

```
 var product=[{"sno":"1","description":"test"}] =Array of object ==>product[0].sno
 var product={"sno":"1","description":"test"} = it presents object.  ==> product.sno
```

Comment: Thanks Himanshu, it worked, it is indeed an array, I could fetch value. I upvoted your answer but it is not reflecting as I have <15 reputation.

Comment: One more thing,  I am getting value but not able to reflect it in indJobDescription html component, i tried interpolation and one,two way binding with input box [ngModel] and [(ngModel)], not sure why it is not reflecting. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: .ts file 

`this.indJobDescription = JSON.parse(this.msg1);
var webtitle =  this.indJobDescription[this.rowNum].nijobdescriptiontitle
alert("webtitle: " + webtitle)`


.html file
`<nb-card-header>Title is: {{webtitle}} </nb-card-header>`
`<input class="JDTitle" 
[ngModel]="webtitle" id="title" type="string" >  `

Comment: It is because local variable defined inside method will have scope on in the method. But you are accessing from template html which can access variable defined at component level. You will have to declare "webtitle" it component level not inside method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to share data between components, input and output properties and shared services.

If component 2 is a child of component 1 then use inputs

```
<component2 [data]="propertyOfComponent1"></component2>
```

and in component 2 decorate the data property as an input

```
@Input() data;
```

After the component has initalised data will be the data passed from component 1. You can access it in the ngOnInit method but not the constructor as it wont be wired up just yet.

If they are not in a parent child relationship use a shared service that is dependency injected into both components constructor.

```
constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
}
```

and both components will get the same instance of the service.

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  data = new SomeObject();
}
```